# SlidingDrawer with RadioButtons as Handle

Tags: android

I have a custom draggable SlidingDrawer using RadioButtons as its Handle. In order to enable the touch events on the RadioButtons I call `return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);` instead of `return true` on the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method. But somehow every time I want to drag my SlidingDrawer I can't drag it up by touching exactly on the RadioButtons, I have to move my finger up a little bit to drag the SlidingDrawer up.

Is there any way to make the SlidingDrawer exactly draggable by touching its RadioButtons without losing the TouchEvent on the RadioButtons itself?

Here's my touch method:

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            if (mLocked) {
                //return false;
            }

            final int action = event.getAction();

            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            final Rect frame = mFrame;
            final View handle = mHandle;

            handle.getHitRect(frame);
            if (!mTracking && !frame.contains((int) x, (int) y)) {
                return false;
            }

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mTracking = true;
                WWHApplication.getListActivityIntance().resizeListView(1800);
                handle.setPressed(true);
                // Must be called before prepareTracking()
                prepareContent();
                // Must be called after prepareContent()
                if (mOnDrawerScrollListener != null) {
                    mOnDrawerScrollListener.onScrollStarted();
                }

                if (mVertical) {
                    final int top = mHandle.getTop();
                    mTouchDelta = (int) y - top;
                    prepareTracking(top);
                } else {
                    final int left = mHandle.getLeft();
                    mTouchDelta = (int) x - left;
                    prepareTracking(left);
                }
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
            }

            //return true;
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);

        }
```

Here's how my handle looks like

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_content_bg_top" />

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_content_bg"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/cb_tab_all"
                        android:layout_width="46dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                        android:button="@drawable/tab_all_selector"
                        android:onClick="true" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/cb_tab_favorites"
                        android:layout_width="84dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                        android:button="@drawable/tab_favorites_selector"
                        android:onClick="true" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/cb_tab_historical"
                        android:layout_width="134dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                        android:button="@drawable/tab_historical_selector"
                        android:onClick="true" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/cb_tab_food"
                        android:layout_width="116dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                        android:button="@drawable/tab_food_selector"
                        android:onClick="true" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_content_bg_bottom" />
        </LinearLayout>
```